# Making a Java-Framework, choose object-Type by string-input

Tags: java, class, oop, dynamic, frameworks

I am trying to make an Java-Framework. What I am trying to do is quite hard to explain, so I made a simple example.

Let's say, I provide a main-Class and a Vehicle-Class:

```
public class Main{
     public static void main(String[] args){
     Vehicle m = new Vehicle();
     System.out.prinln(m.getMaximumVelocity());
}
public class Vehicle{
     protected int maximumVelocity = 0;
     public Vehicle(){}
     public getMaximumVelocity(){
         return this.maximumVelocity;
     }
}
```

This should print out the maximum Velocity of the Vehicle.

Now I want the user to be able, to code his own Vehicle-Classes. For example he could code:

```
public class Bycicle extends Vehicle{
    public Bycicle(){
        this.maximumVelocity=25;
    }   
}
```

The Bycicle-Class should be provided by the user. I don't know in advance, what the name of the Bycicle-Class will be. The user can implement the classes "Car", "Truck", etc. All I know is, that the class has to extend the vehicle-class.

The user should be able to choose, which class should be used, so I need something like this:

```
public class Main{
     public static void main(String[] args){
     Vehicle m = new args[0]();
     System.out.prinln(m.getMaximumVelocity());
}
```

so that `java Main Bycicle` would result in m beeing a Bycicle-Objekt and `java Main Car` would result in m beeing a Car-Object.

Is it somehow possible?

Comment: "*Is it somehow possible?*" - Yes, through reflection. But I wouldn't recommend to do so.

Comment: Thank you very much, it is working! You solved my problem. By the way, why wouldn't you recommend it?